# как исправить lambda выражение?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть подобный код:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit(), state = deduc ...
```

Он если замечает сообщение с буквами то просит их исправить на цифры, но мне нужно сюда добавить исключением слово "Отменить"

Полный код:

```
#Проверка на правильность написания стажа
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit(), state = deduction_from_personal_income_tax_false.rate_per_hour)
async def drive_exp_invalid(message: types.Message):
    return await message.reply("Введите цифрами")
```

Comment: Может как-то так. Поправьте там условия если что
lambda message: message.text != "Отменить" and not message.text.isdigit(), state = deduction_from_personal_income_tax_false.rate_per_hour